# Remove "Move all to next tab group" from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to remove the context menu item "Move all to next tab group" from the tab context menu?

Comment: I looked in my studio and can't find this context item. Can you tell how to find?

Comment: I right click on a tab when there are 2 tab groups open with multiple files open.

Comment: Hmm, this what I guess ... but nothing. Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following applies to Visual Studio 2013:

```
Select the menu item "Tools / Customize"
Select the "Commands" tab.
Select the "Context menu" radio button.
Select "Other Context Menus | Easy MDI Document Window" from the combo box.
Select the "Move All to Previous Tab Group" item and press the "Delete" button.
Select the "Move All to Next Tab Group" item and press the "Delete" button.
```

Comment: Still works in VS 2019